# Oracle SQL Performance

Tags: sql, oracle, performance

I have 2 SQL like that:

1.

```
select * from Customer_source s
where not exist 
(Select 1 from Customer_target t
 where s.CST_ID = t.CST_ID and ( s.NAME <> t.NAME
     or s.GENDER <> t.GENDER
     or .. or ) 
)
```

2. 

```
select * from Customer_source s
where not exist (Select 1 from Customer_target t
 where s.CST_ID = t.CST_ID and ( s.NAME || s.GENDER || ... <> t.NAME || t.GENDER || ... ) 
)
```

Tell me SQL is best Performance

Comment: Alternative 2 is risky - and will not improve performance.

Comment: You have two statements that you can easily benchmark on your own system (which has its own performance characteristics we’d only be guessing). Is either query actually what you want though - do you want the rows in source where there is no row in target with the same `cst_id` and a different value in another column? I would expect this would either be an `exists` Instead or you want to look for the absence of rows with the same value in the other columns.

Comment: @jarlh I agree #2 risky, but there are times where that code would run faster. See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 1):

The two do different things.  For instance, consider just two columns with values like:

```
 Name    Gender
 ABC       M
 ABC      NULL
```

The string concatenation will be `'ABCM' <> 'ABC'` -- they are not equal, so this evaluates to true.

The equality method will be `'ABC' <> 'ABC' OR 'M' <> NULL`.  This evaluates to FALSE OR NULL, which is FALSE.  [Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0bc9036e27e1279f2a6b16e4c434f18d) is a db<>fiddle.

There are other less likely cases where these don't produce the same values.  For instance:

```
ABCfe    male
ABC      female
```

And there are other situations, due to the conversion of the values to strings.  For instance, the time component of a `date` is dropped when using `||`.

So, you should choose the version that does what you intend.  Barring that, you should probably use the first version because it uses native comparisons for each type -- and that seems more appropriate for what you want to do.

I think semantics here are more important than performance.  That is, choose the code that accurately reflects your intentions before you try to optimize it.

Comment: you can nvl before concat

Comment: @PhamHuyGiang . . . I'm not sure what your comment is referring to.  This is answering the question that you actually asked.

Answer (score 0):

The second one is risky as mentioned in the comment as it is concating the values (`a,b` will be matched with `ab, null`), and also indexes will not be used if any.

So according to my experience, the first query is good for performance and also will fetch records with correct logic.

Comment: nvl before concat string

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR; #1 is best for small OLTP queries, #2 is best for large data warehouse queries.**

---

If the relevant columns are indexed, and the query only processes a small percentage of data, then joining with the OR conditions is faster. But if the columns are not indexed, or if the query processes a large percentage of data, then joining with concatenated columns is faster.

The performance comparison boils down to the classic database performance choice - index reads and nested loop joins are better for a small percentage of rows, and full tables scans and hash joins are better for a large percentage of rows.

The OR conditions are sargable - they are simple comparison conditions that can be quickly looked up by traversing the ordered data in one or more index. However, the OR conditions cannot be used in a hash join - Oracle hash joins can only compare two values at a time.

The concatenated columns are not sargable - the combined value is not stored in an index, so Oracle cannot traverse an index to find related values. However, the concatenated columns need just one comparison, so they can be used in a hash anti join.

The test case below processes all of the data, and shows the concatenation version running faster than the OR version. And if you remove the indexes, the OR version performs even worse.

```
--Create tables, insert 1M sample rows, created indexes, and gather optimizer statistics.
create table customer_source(cst_id number, name varchar2(100), gender varchar2(1));
create table customer_target(cst_id number, name varchar2(100), gender varchar2(1));

insert into customer_source select level, rpad(level, 10, 'A'), 'F' from dual connect by level <= 1000000;
insert into customer_target select level, rpad(level, 10, 'A'), 'F' from dual connect by level <= 1000000;

create index customer_source_idx1 on customer_source(cst_id);
create index customer_source_idx2 on customer_source(name);
create index customer_source_idx3 on customer_source(gender);

create index customer_target_idx1 on customer_target(cst_id);
create index customer_target_idx2 on customer_target(name);
create index customer_target_idx3 on customer_target(gender);

begin
    dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user, 'customer_source');
    dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user, 'customer_target');
end;
/

--#1: OR version.
--The explain plan shows a "FILTER" operation that re-reads an index repeatedly.
explain plan for
select * from Customer_source s
where not exists
(Select 1 from Customer_target t
 where s.CST_ID = t.CST_ID and ( s.NAME <> t.NAME
    or s.GENDER <> t.GENDER) 
);

select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);

--#2: Concatenation version.
--The explain plan shows a "HASH JOIN ANTI" operation.
explain plan for
select * from Customer_source s
where not exists (Select 1 from Customer_target t
 where s.CST_ID = t.CST_ID and ( s.NAME || s.GENDER <> t.NAME || t.GENDER) 
);

select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);
```

Normally, the "best looking" query is the one that runs the fastest. Concatenating values is ugly, and as others pointed out, may not even work if your columns are nullable. But in data warehouses, for performance, it's not uncommon to write weird conditions to enable hash joins. While you could always benchmark the queries yourself, it's good to understand these concepts so you know why you're writing weird queries.